# Codeigniter Routes not Redirecting

Tags: codeigniter-2, routes

I am making use of Tank_auth to handle registrations, logins, etc. My CI sits in a subfolder of my domain root e.g. www.domain.com/account/

An Example:

The login controller is as such **auth/login** so my url is **www.domain.com/account/auth/login**

I would like to change **www.domain.com/account/auth/login** to **www.domain.com/account/login** so in my routes.php config file I added this line:

```
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';
```

Now I would expect that when I visit **www.domain.com/account/auth/login** I get taken to  **www.domain.com/account/login**. And if I visit **www.domain.com/account/login** I would remain on that url and the page should load correctly.

Instead when I visit **www.domain.com/account/auth/login** I see the login page and when I visit **www.domain.com/account/login** I get redirected to **www.domain.com/account/auth/login**.

This behaviour seems opposite to what the documentation describes as well as others on SO. I have tried swapping the key and value for the *$route* variable but that just leads to 404s for both urls above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

**[EDIT] - contents of htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove index.php from url
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|js|css|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /account/index.php/$1 [L]

# redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Can you post your .htaccess contents that might be relevant to this. 2. Minor, minor thing but might be worth trying: In the docs, they used single quotes before the equals, and double quotes after the equals.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Thanks for the response. I've added htaccess contents above. I tried the dbl quotes but that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. Can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: What other routes do you have in the routes config, and in what order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect answer, but a workaround I used for something very similar with CI. I think this would do what you're looking for if you add it to your `routes.php` file:

```
$route['(login|logout|register|send_again|activate|forgot_password)'] = 'auth/$1';
```

I'm leaving out some methods from the Auth class, but you get the idea. There's a much more elegant way you could approach this I'm sure, but the basic idea is there.

I used this approach on a project where there were a few routes that basically mapped to static pages. Was using a "pages" controller but the URLs were ending up like: example.com/pages/about. I didn't like that so I came up with the route snippet above.

If there's a better answer I'd love to see it. I remember this bothering me at the time... and looking at it again it still does :)